# emacs , is it running on laptop or on desktop?

Tags: emacs

I have a setting in my .emacs like this
`(display-battery-mode 1)`. It displays my battery status on mode line. That helps me when i am on laptop with fullscreen. But it goes ugly when i am working on desktop `[N/A%][N/A C]`.

So I would like to make it on only when I am working on laptop.

like
`(if OnLaptop

      (display-battery-mode 1))`

Thanks.

UPDATE:
they both are running Linux(Ubuntu)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use the internals of the `battery` package to determine whether or not the battery information was available.  This code snippet should do the trick for you:

```
(require 'battery)
(when (and battery-status-function
       (not (string-match-p "N/A" 
                (battery-format "%B"
                        (funcall battery-status-function)))))
  (display-battery-mode 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
;; If not on AC power line, then display battery status on the mode line
(and (require 'battery nil t)
     (functionp battery-status-function)
     (or (equal (cdr (assoc ?L (funcall battery-status-function))) "on-line")
         (display-battery-mode 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what operating system they're both running on. I would suggest doing something keyed to the hostname. Either via the getenv function (although not all distros export HOSTNAME) or via something like

```
(with-output-to-string
  (call-process "/bin/hostname" nil standard-output nil))
```

If you're on a unix though, I'd consider something like adding "export LAPTOP=1" in your .bashrc and checking for that.

Comment: Since the OS on both systems linux. So this seems to be the easy to implement. I have been thinking of dividing .emacs as per hostname. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a straightforward way but I think you can peek into some files in `/proc` and make an educated guess. If you have a single laptop and a single desktop to differentiate, there should be some signature you can create using the CPU etc.

Comment: thanks, I see battery.el is also looking into `/proc` and `/sys`. I would try to write a function to check the same way as in battery.el. thanks for the answer to my other question. I am trying to get gnus working, I took some of functions from .gnus.

Comment: If this works for you, it's customary to "accept" the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Unfortunately I don't have any non-laptops to try it out on :(

```
(require 'battery)
(setq have-battery-status-p
      (let ((perc-charged (assoc ?p (funcall battery-status-function))))
    (and perc-charged
         (not (zerop (string-to-number (cdr perc-charged)))))))
(if have-battery-status-p
    (display-battery-mode 1))
```

---

**EDIT**

To break it down from the inside out, `(funcall battery-status-function)` returns an [alist](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Association-List-Type.html), for which we want the 'p' (as a character) element, as this contains the percentage of battery charge remaining.

So `perc-charged` will be something like `nil` if there is no 'p' element in the battery status alist, or `(112 . "97")` if the battery is 97% charged, or (I'm guessing) `(112 . "N/A")` if battery status is unavailable.

Finally, if `perc-charged` is non-nil and the `cdr` of this value is non-zero when converted to a number (as "N/A" will be when using `string-to-number` conversion), we assume a battery is present.

I've fleshed out the example to what should now be a fully working example also.

Comment: could you explain what this supposed to do?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Seems I cant accept more than one answer

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
;; load these only if using GUI emacs 
(when (display-graphic-p)
```

Comment: good option to know, though its not really desired answer in this case, Since I use emacs with X in both cases.